# Count of drilled down rows with condition in tableau

Tags: data-analysis, window-functions, tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I'm using parameter action to drill down to level 3. I have a requirement to show:

the count of drilled open rows and (this will be denominator)

the count of rows in drilled open rows where sales values is less than 20,000. (this will be numerator)

For eg: In the visual level 1 is Category, level 2 is Sub-Category and level 3 is Region. So here in drilled open rows of bookcases I should get 1 as numerator and 4 as denominator (We have 4 regions and only south region has sales less than 20,000)

Please help...TIA!